# How to implement items to each room in a python3 text adventure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, adventure

I'm quite new to oop, but I wanted to learn something about it and so I started to write a text adventure in Python3.

After a long time reading through many suggestions and methods on how to get started, I decided to go with the cmd-module for parsing and classes for rooms and other stuff. I don't want to write so much adventure data into the code so I stumbled upon the idea to use the json module to outsource it. So far, I managed to switch between rooms and now I want to have items in them.

I tried to add another attribute to the Room-class, which should be a list of items available in this specific room. Now I'm stuck on how to make instances of these items in the room in order to print out the description of them in this order:

```
1.) Room name 
2.) Room description
3.) Item1 description
4.) Item2 description
5.) ...
```

The 1.) and 2.) got printed already with do_look()

Here is the main game loop:

```py
import cmd
from rooms import get_room

class Play(cmd.Cmd):
    """Base class for the game"""
    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        cmd.Cmd.prompt = '> '
        self.location = get_room(1)    
        self.do_look()

    def move(self, direction):
        new_id = self.location.exit_to(direction)
        if new_id is None:
            print('You can not go there')
        else:
            self.location = get_room(new_id)
            self.do_look()

    def do_look(self, *args):
        """Print the Room description."""
        print(self.location.name)
        print("")
        print(self.location.desc)
        print("")

    def do_north(self, *args): #Example direction command
        """Move north"""
        self.move('north')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    play = Play()
    play.cmdloop()
```

And here is the rooms module (with already added "items" attribute):

```py
import json

def get_room(_id):
    # ret = None
    with open(str(_id) + '.json', 'r') as f:
        jsontext = f.read()
        d = json.loads(jsontext)
        # d["_id"] = _id 
        ret = Room(**d)
    return ret

class Room:
    def __init__(self, _id = 0, name = '', desc = '' exits = {}, items = []):
        self._id = _id
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.exits =  exits
        self.items = items

    def exit_to(self, _dir):
        if _dir in self.exits:
            return self.exits[_dir]
        else:
            return None
```

And a typical .json looks like this (Filename: 1.json):

```
{   
    "_id" : "1", 
    "name" : "The First Room",
    "desc" : "You wake up in the First Room ...",
    "exits" : {"north" : 4},
    "items" : ["puppet", "gun"]
    }
```

I've also created a items module, but i dont know how to connect it to the Rooms:

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, desc, desc_in_room):
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.desc_in_room = desc_in_room


""" This is the first and unfinished attempt to deal with it,
    but I think this is not gonna work:"""

def make_item(self, _id):
     with open(str(_id) + '.json', 'r') as f:
        jsontext = f.read()
        d = json.jsonloads(jsontext)
            for i in d["items"]:
                with open(str(i) + '.json', 'r') as fil:
                    itemtext = f.read()
                    item_dict = json.jsonloads(itemtext)
                    """Dont know..."""
    return ret
```

So any advice on how to extract the "puppet" from the list inside the dict and converting it to an Item instance and printing its descriptions, would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of Python is that there is a library for most any common operation - and lots of non common ones. In your case, [JsonPickle](https://jsonpickle.github.io/) looks like a good choice. You can create a template json from a room then modify it eslewhere and re hydrate as needed. I've written an example for you below;

first

**pip-install jsonpickle**

then run the code below

```
import jsonpickle
import pprint


class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, desc, desc_in_room):
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.desc_in_room = desc_in_room

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}, {self.desc}, {self.desc_in_room}"


class Room:
    def __init__(self, _id=0, name='', desc='', exits=None, items=None):
        self._id = _id
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.exits = exits if exits is not None else {}
        self.items = items if items is not None else []

    def exit_to(self, _dir):
        if _dir in self.exits:
            return self.exits[_dir]
        else:
            return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myroom = Room(1, "First", "An eerie door leads to your destiny",
                  items=[Item("Item1", "Hammer", "Large and heavy"), Item("Item2", "Sword", "Old and rusty")])

    frozen = jsonpickle.encode(myroom)
    print(frozen)

    # YIELDS
    """{"_id": 1, "desc": "An eerie door leads to your destiny", "exits": {}, "items": 
    [{"desc": "Hammer", "desc_in_room": "Large and heavy", "name": "Item1", "py/object": "__main__.Item"}, 
    {"desc": "Sword", "desc_in_room": "Old and rusty", "name": "Item2", "py/object": "__main__.Item"}], 
    "name": "First", "py/object": "__main__.Room"}"""

    # CHANGE AT WILL
    modified = """{"_id": 1, "desc": "An eerie door leads to your destiny", "exits": {}, "items": 
    [{"desc": "Feather", "desc_in_room": "Harmless", "name": "Item1", "py/object": "__main__.Item"}, 
    {"desc": "Sword", "desc_in_room": "Old and rusty", "name": "Item2", "py/object": "__main__.Item"}], 
    "name": "Second", "py/object": "__main__.Room"}"""

    new_room = jsonpickle.decode(modified)  # type: Room
    print(new_room.name)
    for i in new_room.items:
        print(i)

    # YIELDS the Following. Note the new name for the room and for the Hammer
    """
    Second
    Item1, Feather, Harmless
    Item2, Sword, Old and rusty
    """
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply! I didn't know that module before. But I presume that this is more about creating new rooms in general then sticking instances of items to them, isn't it? Maybe my opening post wasn't clear about this: I can make room instances with a list of strings (i.e. items : "puppet", "gun"). But i wonder how to make actual Item instances out of the lists.

Comment: The principal is the same - I was just being lazy. I edited the above to show you that it works if you have non-empty items. Note that I simply changed the relevant parts of the string, decode the string and vala - a new room with items populated : )